# How do i make this shape for a boostrap div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to make the bootstrap div col-xs-2 have the form of the attached images, there are two.

I hope you can help me!

Greetings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try an SVG image

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, thanks

Comment: I currently have a circle, but do not use me.
.status-box {
    background: #dddddd;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with borders on :before & :after 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWOwpz

```css
.container {
  margin-top:40px;
}
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.arrow--grey {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.arrow--green {
  background-color: #037b03;
}
.arrow:before {
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 40px solid #fff;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.arrow:after {
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.arrow--grey:before, .arrow--grey:after {
  content: "";
}
.arrow--green:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="arrow arrow--grey col-xs-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="arrow arrow--green col-xs-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello webpandit is very good example, but if you put some connection as paragraph or title breaks everything, I am seeing if it can be solved, but I do not get to walks

Comment: The above code is what you asked for in the post, use that as a start and try the rest by yourself. If you can mark it as the answer/solution, that  would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

And [this polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-clip-path-polyfill) fo Firefox support.

More about [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)